# Как я могу рассортировать все элементы по типам?

Tags: c++

Надо чтобы `to_vector` работал и принимал разный тип данных.

```
template <typename T1, typename... T2>
vector<T1>to_vector(T2&& ... ts) {
    vector<T1> vec;
    (vec.push_back(ts), ...);
    return vec;
}

to_vector(1, 2, 33, "test", 5.6f, 2.14, 2.55);
```

Comment: И как вы себе представляете вектор, хранящий элементы разных типов? Если бы они были хотя бы приводимы к некоторому общему типу... Ну, или воспользуйтесь чем-то типа `any`...

Comment: Вы хотите сказать хранить указатели на объект?

Comment: Я просто спросил как можно сделать, если нельзя тогда ладно.

Comment: Рассортировать элементы по типам вполне можно, а вот запихнуть объекты разных типов в один вектор (что по факту делается в вопросе) - нет.

Comment: чего собственно  надо добиться. Вместо того чтобы  спросить как из камня вырезать яйцо из которого может вылупиться цыпленок, спросите , где несушка.

Comment: Кстати, вот вопрос - а зачем? С большим подозрением отношусь к проектам, в которых нужны `variant` или `any`, да и `union` тоже. Как, кстати, и к `dynamic_cast`. Не то что я категорически против - но мне всегда кажется, что это результат непродуманности.

Comment: @Harry union  часто используется при общении с оборудованием или по сети с чемт-то примитивным. any является аналогом встроенных конструкций многих моделей данных. json, sgml-семейства, списки в Питоне, и пр. Часто приходилось писать его аналоги, вот и предложили стандартизировать.

Comment: @Swift Ну, понятно, что union - тяжкое аппаратное наследие, когда с памятью проблемы... :) Но опять же - чистый union и variant/any - две очень большие разницы. Да и строго работать с union в современном С++ с его ограничениями на то же выравнивание, strict aliacing и т.д. - задача не из приятных...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализация вектора подразумевает одинаковый тип объектов, а так-же их возможность копировать, удалять. Можно создать свой собственный объект, который может хранить разные типы объектов. Но программист должен сам позаботиться о каких типах он будет заботиться и сам реализовать удобства. Примерно так :

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++11 univect.cpp
# include <string>
using std::string;
# include <vector>
using std::vector;
# include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class UniMember {
public:
  enum { Null , Int , String } ;
  void * mem {nullptr};
  int type {Null};
  UniMember(){}
  UniMember(UniMember && x):mem{x.mem},type{x.type}{x.mem=nullptr;x.type=Null;}
  UniMember(UniMember const & );
  UniMember(int );
  UniMember(string const &);
  UniMember(string && );
  ~UniMember();
} ;

UniMember::UniMember(int i){
  mem = new int{i};
  type = Int ;  }

UniMember::UniMember(string const & s){
  mem = new string{s};
  type = String ;  }

UniMember::UniMember(string && s){
  mem = new string{std::move(s)};
  type = String ;  }  

UniMember::UniMember(UniMember const & x) :type{x.type} {
  switch(type) {
  case  Int : mem = new int{*(int*)x.mem} ;break;
  case  String : mem = new string{* (string*)x.mem};break;
  default: ; } }

UniMember::~UniMember() {
  switch(type) {
  case  Int : delete (int*)mem;break;
  case  String : delete (string*)mem;break;
  default: ; } }

int main(){
  vector<UniMember> v = { 7 , string{"7"} } ;
  v.push_back(8);
  v.push_back(string{"8"});
  UniMember b = std::move(v.back());
  v.pop_back();
  if(b.type == UniMember::String)
    cout<<"back = \""<<(*(string*)b.mem)<<"\"\n";
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant в помощь

Comment: @Swift Спасибо за `variant`, но это в стандарте `c++17`. А я написал в `c++11`. Стандартные решения я не очень люблю, они со скрытыми проблемами очень часто.

Comment: ваш класс практически реализует урезанный any, просто вместо перечисления там используется `typeid`. Еше лучше воспользоваться emplace_back  вместо push_back и позаботиться о выравнивании

Comment: @Swift `any` так-же в `c++17`. Там разные размеры типов, а нужно для вектора один фиксированный размер, то-есть указатель на `any`. Приходим к той-же проблеме. `variant` - это `union` , очень непрактично будет насчёт памяти.

Comment: any имеет постоянный размер, он  хранит указатель и typeid, иначе невозможно.. Это  variant и optional статические. См. пример ниже.

Comment: any не подходит, слишком сложно.

Comment: @Darth Vader учти что это вариант не проще, а просто реалтзует частный случай any, и обязательно выделяет память под каждый элемент, не перемещая если возможно, дефрагментация памяти. А для упорядочивания придется делать то же самое. Если важна устойчивость, то этот код нужно дорабатывать. А так же дорабатывать для любого нового хранимого типа

Comment: Можно пойти по стопам Qt и для маленьких типов записывать значение вместо указателя , а указатель хранить в виде intptr_t

Answer (score 0):

При наличии поддержки `<any>` все просто

```
// g++ -Wall -std=c++17
#include <string>
#include <any>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;

template <typename T1, typename... T2>
void to_range(T1&& dest, T2&& ... ts) {
    (dest.emplace_back(ts), ...);
}

int main(){
  vector<std::any> v = { 7 , string{"7"} } ;
  v.emplace_back(1.0f);
  v.emplace_back(string{"8"});

  to_range( v, 3 , 4.6f, string{"boo"} );

  for ( auto val : v)
  if (val.type() == typeid(int))
        std::cout << "int: " << std::any_cast<int>(val) << "\n";
    else if (val.type() == typeid(std::string))
        std::cout << "string: " << std::any_cast<std::string>(val) << "\n";
    else if (val.type() == typeid(float))
        std::cout << "float: " << std::any_cast<float>(val) << "\n";
}
```

`to_range` - это `to_vector`, обобщенный для использования с любым контейнером, который позволит делать вот такое надругательство над собой.

Теперь, если значения нужно рассортировать, то можно использовать стандартные сортировки, следует установить порядок какой `typeid` (возвращаемый в `type()`) "больше" какого, чтобы написать предикат.